# Deprecate enum value in Swift

Tags: swift, enums, annotations

Is it possible to mark an enum value in Swift as deprecated?

I tried

```swift
enum RelativeDays {
   case today, tomorrow, @available(*, deprecated, message: "Don't live in the past! Cherish the moment and look forward to the future!") yesterday
}
```

But I get a compilation error saying that an identifier is expected where the annotation is.

Comment: You have the same enum case declared 2x, how do you expect that to work? Moreover, need to have the case on its own line to be able to use the `@available`

Comment: @DávidPásztor my bad with the duplication - I screwed it up when creating the artificial example. ;) Regarding the `case`: yes, that turned out to be the solution as per the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it's just the syntax:

```
enum RelativeDays {
   case today
   @available(*, deprecated, message: "Don't live in the past! Cherish the moment and look forward to the future!")
   case tomorrow
}
```

works:
[image]