# Deprecating an enum case in Swift

Tags: swift

I have following enumeration in my SDK and I'd like to deprecate `reconnecting` and `connecting` cases for customers:

```swift
enum ConnectionState: Equatable {
   case connecting
   case reconnecting
   case connected
   case disconnected
}
```

I found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71354470/deprecate-enum-value-in-swift) and applied suggested answer which is:

```swift
enum ConnectionState: Equatable {
   @available(*, deprecated)
   case connecting
   @available(*, deprecated)
   case reconnecting
   case connected
   case disconnected
}
```

Xcode 14.3 generates a warning as expected:

[image: warning]

...but there is no warning for the `switch` statement, which also has uses of the deprecated `.connecting` and `reconnecting`.

Do you know why it doesn't work there? Here's the minimal example code you can try in any project/playground. I would appreciate any help!

```swift
// Let's ignore this condition
// This should be something more realistic, but it's for test purposes only
var x: ConnectionState = Int.random(in: 1...10) % 2 == 0 ? .connected : .reconnecting
        
switch x {
case .connecting:
  debugPrint("connecting")
case .connected:
  debugPrint("connected")
case .reconnecting:
  debugPrint("reconnecting")
case .disconnected:
  debugPrint("disconnected")
}
```

I tried to apply suggested answer from StackOverflow's question I mentioned, but it didn't help. I also read some materials about the `@available` keyword, but couldn't find any example that's similar to mine.

Answer (score 1):

switch statements must be exhaustive in Swift, so even if an enum case is marked as deprecated, as long as the case exists, users of the enum must always reference those enum cases when switching over a variable of the enum type.

This means that if the compiler warned against the enum case being deprecated, people who have warnings as errors enabled wouldn't be able to compile their code just because a library developer marked an enum case as deprecated without actually removing said case.

So what you are looking for isn't possible and you shouldn't try to do it either.

If consumers of your library are trying to declare properties of the deprecated enum cases, they will get the deprecation warning as expected. However, simply referencing the deprecated cases while switching over an enum variable will not and should not trigger a deprecation warning.

Comment: Good answer. (Voted.) Not getting a warning when you use a deprecated switch case seems wrong somehow. It seems to me that the more nuanced solution would be to teach the compiler that deprecated (but not removed) enums can never be treated as hard errors, and only generate a warning. But that would probably be a pretty big change...

Comment: @DuncanC it definitely feels somewhat counter intuitive on first thought that deprecated switch cases get different treatment than referencing a deprecated enum case outside the switch statement. However, switches being exhaustive make this quite a tricky problem to solve in a better way.

Comment: I also suspect another reason why this doesn't trigger a deprecation warning is because if you're simply switching over a deprecated case, but not directly declaring it, resolving the breaking change once the case is removed is much easier than if you were directly declaring it and hence no warning is necessary.

Comment: True. And since switch cases must be exhaustive, there is little or nothing you can do until the case is actually removed. I would still like to know about deprecated enum cases in advance so I could do analysis on my code and see if I needed to make any changes to my business logic though.

Answer (score 0):

You could always rename the case to `something_DEPRECATED`. This would force the users of your library to review and fix their code, but the fix is trivial and wouldn't force them to re-engineer anything immediately. At the same time, it would make all users fully aware that the case had become deprecated and would discourage any new use.

Comment: I up-voted it because it is a reasonable suggestion.

Comment: @DuncanC Sorry but I disagree, I think it's a very bad suggestion to rename an enum case like this specially when there is such a good tool as `@available` that can be used and it does not force the user to do anything as the answer claims. And the case will not be marked as deprecated in the documentation either. Not to mention any eventual hustle with unit tests.

Comment: And you might also have an enum case that is or contains the word deprecated for one reason or another that is relevant for the app so this kind of magic number solution should be avoided imo.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I would think of this as "hard" deprecation. It deliberately breaks existing code that uses the deprecated case, but in a way that is trivial to fix. If you want to move consumers of the library away from the deprecated code quickly then this approach may be more effective than ```@available```, given the limited effectiveness of this (as described in the OP). The two approaches can be used together, of course. Regarding naming conflicts, if the suffix uses underscore and uppercase then this will never conflict with any regular enum that follows more usual naming conventions.

Comment: I wasn’t talking about name conflicts but rather that deprecated is a normal English word and might be used in a case name for other reason so this solution might not be so clear. Hence my reference to magic numbers